# How do I style a List View Web Part?

Tags: 2013, web-part, style

I've included a List View Web part on a page. I want to show a list of links. How do I style it? Such as changing the CSS, adding icons etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is a bit vague, only because there are quite a few ways to do, and doing an initial search you will find quite a few resources.

I will list out 3 possible methods for you:

1. Edit the page with SharePoint Designer.
2. Use a content editor and/or script editor web part on the page.
3. Use display templates - in your list webpart properties there is an option at the bottom of the page to a link to a JSLink file.  This is a JavaScript file that SharePoint will use to create a rendering template for your list view.

Which one should you use?  It depends.
If you want to re-use the style, then look at #3.
If it's one off and you need a quick solution use #2
If you need the code to not be modified by a user with contribute permissions, and it's a one off look at #1

There are actually a few more advanced methods but these are the most common.  I encourage you to look at Microsoft MSDN site regarding JSLink files - they provide quite a bit of power.

Comment: Thanks I've been testing out JS Link and it seems to do what I need with lists. Are JS Link files considered display templates themselves?

Comment: Probably not 100% - but they work the same. With "Display Templates" you deploy those to the master pages library and they become available for selection in your search web parts.